# unable to perform action from InternetExplorerdriver in selenium, as URL will be launched but cannot perform any action.Please provide a solution

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\Users\\madhusudhan\\Desktop\\selenium\\IEDriverServer_x64_2.48.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.zoho.com/login.html");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.switchTo().frame(0);
        driver.findElement(By.id("lid")).sendKeys("madh@rx.com");
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        driver.findElement(By.className("logo")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment your below mentioned lines from your code and try again...

// driver.switchTo().frame(0);
// driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

Please let me know if facing any other issue.